# django rest framework installation fails

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

How do I install the REST framework in django?

The following command throws an error on Mac OS X:

```
pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi
```

**Error:**

> Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement djangorestframework-jsonapi (from versions) No matching
>   distribution found for djangorestframework-jsonapi

Comment: If you want to install Django REST Framework you have to issue the command: `pip install djangorestframework`. Your question and your code example don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pip3 install djangorestframework-jsonapi` this command.

Comment: No, you should not simply sudo install packages. At least suggest the usage of a virtualenv or identify a clear need for sudo.

Comment: put the path of pipe which is installed in your virtual environment inside the bin folder e.g ENV/bin/pip3 install djangorestframework-jsonapi. Check it's work.

Comment: sudo -H pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing Django Rest Framework or are you installing the JSON API?  If it is just DRF, check the installation docs: 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation

Otherwise, please provide more info like what version of Python and your OS as well as what version of the library you are installing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not best practice to sudo install like Yogesh suggested. This is because: 1. Isolation is important and 2. It's always good to know exactly what your dependencies are for your application.

With that being said, it's best to install your package in either a virtualenv or docker environment.

`virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi`

Answer (score 0):

Its simple if you want to install Django rest framework on your machine make sure your pip version is up to date.

use this command:

```
 pip install djangorestframework
```

If this command is not working use this one:

```
 pip3 install djangorestframework
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.