# Error installing django rest framework pypi

Tags: python, pypi, setup.py

Here's my setup.py:

```
install_requires=[
            "Django",
            "djangorestframework",
        ],
```

However, when I try to install my library, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangorestframework (from my-library) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for djangorestframework
```

What is wrong with my setup.py? I have checked the homepage of django rest framework, and it says I can install it using this command: `pip install djangorestframework`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670937/django-rest-framework-installation-fails

Answer (score 0):

In installed apps it goes

```
'rest_framework',
```